# Nodejs Angular profile

Tags: node.js, angular, profile

I have a probleme with my Angular Application, I want to sent the data of user in profile root in Angular 5 but it's not work.

**I use nodejs ang angular 5.**

An error like look :

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

My root nodejs profile :

```
router.get('/dashboard', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), 
    function(req, res) {
       User.findById({_id : req.user.id}, function(err, user) {
       res.json(user);
    });
});
```

Angular profile.service.ts

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getProfile() {
     const uri = 'http://localhost:4000/api/dashboard';
     return this.http.get(uri).map(res => {
        return res;
     });
  }
```

Angular profile.component.ts

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

   profiles: any;
   constructor( private prof: ProfileService) {}

   ngOnInit() { this.getProfile(); }

   getProfile() {
      this.prof.getProfile().subscribe(res => {
        this.profiles = res;
      });
   }
}
```

Html view

```
<div *ngFor="let profile of profiles">
   {{ profile.email }}
</div>
```

Comment: A good place to start would be logging inside getProfile() to see what is being returned from the API call. Additionally, if you are returning an observable or a promise you can bind it directly in the template with the async pipe. Lastly, I'd suggest that you make use of TypeScripts type checking so that you aren't relying on anonymous objects.

Answer (score 0):

On your backend your service is returning a single profile which is an object.

```
findById -> object
/dashboard -> object
getProfile(http get) -> object
```

So you need to show your variable as an object.

```
 export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

   profile: object;
   constructor( private prof: ProfileService) {}

   ngOnInit() { this.getProfile(); }

   getProfile() {
      this.prof.getProfile().subscribe(res => {
        this.profile = res;
      });
   }
}
```

html

```
<code>
   {{ profile | json}}
</code>

<label>
   {{ profile.email}}
</label>
```

Comment: if I use your method it's work i can display json in my view, but i have a little error                                                    
     ProfileComponent.html:11 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefinedProfileComponent.html:11 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Comment: @ValentinValentyn what is your json looks like?

Comment: { "_id": "5af563f17f434b31907712a3", "nom": "frfrf", "email": "fr@fr.fr", "password": "$2a$10$KBLWFjNC3dvIFl9W2wQJeOxgBDdzWNLWUKoIJ64cWBjVchM/Fq.Fy", "__v": 0 }

Answer (score 0):

ngFor iterates over arrays. To iterate over object try this

*ngFor="let profilekey of Object.keys(profiles)"
And inside expression,

{{ profiles[profilekey].email }}

Answer (score 0):

I find one method and it's work

in my service I add

```
  getProfile() {
        const uri = 'http://localhost:4000/api/dashboard';
        return this.http.get<any>(uri).map(res => {
        return res;
     });
  }
```

my component

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

   profile = []
   constructor( private prof: ProfileService) {}

   ngOnInit() {   this.getProfile();   }


   getProfile() {
       this.prof.getProfile().subscribe(
       res => this.profile = res,
       );
   }
}
```

my view

```
{{ profile.email}}
```